# Parsing output txt "show ip route" to csv

Tags: python-3.6

I need to use python code to parse a text file with the output of the routing table from several routers (I will provide an example of a text file). I want to get a structure in which the title or the first column with the name of the router goes and then the parameters (routing protocol, network, mask, AD, nexthop, time). But with the name of the router I can’t.

This is a text file to parse:

```
..................THIS IS THE HOST IP ADDRESS...................
192.168.100.1

R1>show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      90.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 11 subnets
B        90.1.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
B        90.2.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
B        90.3.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
B        90.4.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
B        90.5.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
B        90.6.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
B        90.7.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
B        90.8.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
B        90.9.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
B        90.10.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
 --More-- B        90.11.0.0 [20/0] via 192.168.100.2, 15:02:50
      192.168.100.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.100.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
L        192.168.100.1/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
R1>

..................THIS IS THE HOST IP ADDRESS...................
192.168.100.2

R2>show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      90.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 11 subnets
S        90.1.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
S        90.2.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
S        90.3.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
S        90.4.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
S        90.5.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
S        90.6.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
S        90.7.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
S        90.8.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
S        90.9.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
S        90.10.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
 --More-- S        90.11.0.0 is directly connected, Null0
      192.168.100.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.100.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
L        192.168.100.2/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
R2>

..................THIS IS THE HOST IP ADDRESS...................
192.168.100.3

R3>show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      192.168.100.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.100.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
L        192.168.100.3/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
R3>
```

This is the result in the CSV that I get:

```
 protocol,network,mask,AD,nextHop,interface,time
 B,90.1.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.2.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.3.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.4.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.5.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.6.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.7.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.8.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.9.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.10.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 B,90.11.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13 
 C,192.168.100.0,24,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 L,192.168.100.1,32,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 S,90.1.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0,
 S,90.2.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 S,90.3.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 S,90.4.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0,
 S,90.5.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 S,90.6.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 S,90.7.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0,
 S,90.8.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 S,90.9.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 S,90.10.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0,
 S,90.11.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 C,192.168.100.0,24,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 L,192.168.100.2,32,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 C,192.168.100.0,24,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 L,192.168.100.3,32,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 C,192.168.100.0,24,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 L,192.168.100.3,32,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0,
```

The result that I want to get:

```
 device,protocol,network,mask,AD,nextHop,interface,time
 R1,B,90.1.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.2.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.3.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.4.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.5.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.6.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.7.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.8.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.9.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.10.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13
 R1,B,90.11.0.0,,[20/0],192.168.100.2,,02:47:13 
 R1,C,192.168.100.0,24,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 R1,L,192.168.100.1,32,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 R2,S,90.1.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0,
 R2,S,90.2.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 R2,S,90.3.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 R2,S,90.4.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0,
 R2,S,90.5.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 R2,S,90.6.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 R2,S,90.7.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0,
 R2,S,90.8.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 R2,S,90.9.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 R2,S,90.10.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0,
 R2,S,90.11.0.0,,,is directly connected,Null0, 
 R2,C,192.168.100.0,24,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 R2,L,192.168.100.2,32,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 R3,C,192.168.100.0,24,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0, 
 R3,L,192.168.100.3,32,,is directly connected,FastEthernet0/0,
```

This is my code

```
     from collections import ChainMap
     import csv
     import re

     regex_device = re.compile('(?P<Router>^.+)[>#]')

     regex = re.compile('(?P<protocol>\S+) +'
                '(?P<network>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/?'
                '(?P<mask>\d*) +'
                '(?P<AD>\[\d+/\d+\]) +via +'
                '(?P<nextHop>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\,\ +'
                '(?P<interface>\S+\d+/\d+)*'
                '(?P<time>\S+)')


     regex_direktly = re.compile('(?P<protocol>[L|C|S]) +'
                        '(?P<network>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d\d?\d?)/?'
                        '(?P<mask>\d*) +'
                        '(?P<nextHop>.*), +'
                        '(?P<interface>\S+\d/\d+|.*)'
                        '(?P<time>\S*)')

     result = []
     result1 = []

     with open('output_route_table.txt') as data:
         for line in data:
            match = regex_device.search(line)
            if match:
               result1.append(match.groupdict())

     with open('output_route_table.txt') as data:
         for line in data:
            match = regex.search(line)
            if match:
               result.append(match.groupdict())

     with open('output_route_table.txt') as data:
        for line in data:
           match = regex_direktly.search(line)
           if match:
              result.append(match.groupdict())

     with open('output_route_table.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=list(result[0].keys()))
        writer.writeheader()
        for d in result:
            writer.writerow(d)
```

Comment: How do you want to choose what lines to keep? I don't understand how you want to keep only 3 lines from that long output

Comment: I'm sorry.
The result I want to get all the lines with routes, just in the example showed only three.

Comment: Soooo... You'll need to `result.append({'device':'router_name_here', **match.groupdict()}` to add the column. As for the router name... is the input a single file or multiple files? Why in your code are you opening the input file 3 times? Are the first two even outputting anything?

Comment: As for the input file, it does not change, and it is more correct to open it once and conduct parsing. But here I also did not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     with open('output_route_table.txt') as data:
         for line in data:
            match = regex_device.search(line)
            if match:
               result1.append(match.groupdict())

     with open('output_route_table.txt') as data:
         for line in data:
            match = regex.search(line)
            if match:
               result.append(match.groupdict())

     with open('output_route_table.txt') as data:
        for line in data:
           match = regex_direktly.search(line)
           if match:
              result.append(match.groupdict())
```

This parts opens the file 3 times and first one scrapes the router names... to a list you never use. You need to go through the file only once and save the last router you saw (routes belong to the last router mentioned so far).

```
     last_router = ""
     with open('output_route_table.txt') as data:
         for line in data:
            is_router = regex_device.search(line)
            if is_router:
               last_router = is_router.group('Router') # get the name of the router only
            is_route = regex.search(line) or regex_direktly.search(line) # gets first non-None value or None if all are None
            if is_route:
               result.append({'device': last_router, **is_route.groupdict()})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the code turned out to be correct in this form (I replaced "** match.groupdict ()" in the last line with "** is_route.groupdict ()")

Comment: Ah, right. I renamed the variables but forgot this one place!